# Google Earth Engine Import shape as draggable Layer

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, import

How to import a shape or image into GEE and drag it around like the self-drawn imports?

Edit: the asset is uploaded and also added to the map, but it´s projected according to its coordinates, I want to free it from the coordinates and drag it freely

Answer (score 1):

By now it is possible to do that, but do be careful that geometries with many vertices will crash your browser. Unless it is very simple manipulation you should definitely do your editing beforehand in another GIS program.

```
function setGeom(geometry){
  Map.drawingTools().addLayer([geometry])
}

var table = ee.FeatureCollection("YOUR/IMPORT/HERE");
var geom = table.geometry().evaluate(setGeom)
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to upload a shapefile is to zip all the extensions associated with a shapefile and ingest it as an asset. On the left-hand side is the Assets tab, where you can upload the same.

Comment: I've Ingested it as an Asset, but when I add it with `Map.addLayer()` it isn't draggable.

Comment: What do you mean by draggable? GEE automatically recognizes the projection and loads your asset.

Comment: I mean draggable like the geometries one can draw yourself

Comment: An assets geometry cannot be manipulated like the geometries you draw in the code editor.You would do that in a GIS prior to ingestion.